# How to make constructor initialize to all 0's?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I am new to Java and trying to figure this out.

My NVector class is supposed to store numbers in an array double v[n]. 
The constructor, takes dimension n and sets all elements to 0: NVector(int n)

Below is what I have, and I am getting an error

```
public class NVector
{

double[] v;

NVector(int n)
{
    this = new double[n];//Error: double cannot be converted to NVector
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        v[i] = 0;

    }
}
```

I tried:

```
v = new double[n];
```

But that dosent work either. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: `"...and I am getting an error"` -- Always show the error in the text of your question.

Comment: What does "that doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need

```
this.v = new double[n];
```

`this` refers to current object, you want current object's v so `this.v`

Answer (score 1):

`this.v = new double[n];` should work.

`this` mean, current instance of `NVector` class. You can't assign a `double` array to any instance of `NVector` class.

Answer (score 0):

this should serve

```
public class NVector
{

Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();

public Vector<Double> NVector(int n)
{

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        v.add(i);

    }
    return v;

}
```